# How to send an attachment with mandrill to show RSVP buttons on outlook?

Tags: python, smtp, icalendar, mandrill

Below code sends an ics attachment and shows RSVP button while sends with gmail smtp

```
    filename = "invite.ics"
part2 = MIMEBase('text', "calendar", method="REQUEST", name=filename)
# part2.set_type('text/calendar; charset=UTF-8; method=REQUEST; component = VEVENT')
part2.set_type("text/calendar")
part2.set_payload(calendar.to_ical())
encoders.encode_base64(part2)
part2.add_header('Content-Description', filename)
part2.add_header("Content-class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage")
part2.add_header("Filename", filename)
part2.add_header('Content-Disposition', "inline; filename= %s" % filename)
```

but doesn't show RSVP button while we send an email with mandrill.

Comment: Please provide the resulting full MIME message and ics file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with Mandrill.

> Currently, we aren't able to support the text/calendar multipart format—which is typically the format being used to add those event invitations in emails. When Mandrill's parser hits these kinds of message parts (text/calendar), it will skip over them since they don't conform to anything that it knows how to abstract away. It's not true text or HTML, attachment or embedded image. In the future, we'll look into adding special support for this particular form of message as it's quite popular, but I can't provide any specific ETA on when that might be. In the meantime, you might consider generating the .ics files and attaching them, just as you might with other types of attachments through the Mandrill API or SMTP integration.
>   The Mandrill Crew